# I get error as "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a data warehouse. I have 4 table on public schema they are customer, product, addressee and orders

Then I created this tables on my olap schema

```
CREATE TABLE olap.time 
(
        idtime SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        year integer,
        month integer,
        week integer,
        day integer
);

CREATE TABLE olap.addressees 
(
        idaddressee integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        zip char(6) NOT NULL,
        address varchar(60) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE olap.customers 
(
        idcustomer  varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY ,
        name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        city varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        zip char(6) NOT NULL,
        address varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        email varchar(40),
        phone varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        regon char(9)
);

CREATE TABLE olap.fact
(
        idtime integer NOT NULL,
        idaddressee integer NOT NULL,
        idcustomer varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        idfact integer NOT NULL,
        price numeric(7,2),
        PRIMARY KEY (idtime, idaddressee, idcustomer),
        FOREIGN KEY (idaddressee) REFERENCES olap.addressees(idaddressee),
        FOREIGN KEY (idcustomer) REFERENCES olap.customers(idcustomer),
        FOREIGN KEY (idtime) REFERENCES olap.time(idtime)
);
```

After the creating tables I run these queries

```
INSERT INTO olap.time (year, month, week, day)
    SELECT date_part('year', date), date_part('month', date), date_part('week', date), date_part('day', date) 
    FROM public.orders 
    GROUP BY public.orders.date
    ORDER BY public.orders.date;

    INSERT INTO olap.addressees(idaddressee, name, zip, address)
        SELECT idaddressee, name, zip, address 
        FROM public.addressee;

    INSERT INTO olap.customers (idcustomer, name, city, zip, address, email, phone, regon)
        SELECT idcustomer, name, city, zip, address, email, phone, regon 
        FROM public.customer;
```

And then I try to do these set of query

```
INSERT INTO olap.fact (idtime, idaddressee, idcustomer, idfact, price)
    SELECT olap.time.idtime, olap.addressees.idaddressee, olap.customers.idcustomer, COUNT(*), public.orders.price
    FROM (((public.orders
    INNER JOIN olap.time ON (date_part('year', public.orders.date) = olap.time.year AND date_part('month', public.orders.date) = olap.time.month AND date_part('week', public.orders.date) = olap.time.week) AND date_part('day', public.orders.date) = olap.time.day)
    INNER JOIN olap.addressees ON public.orders.idaddressee = olap.addressees.idaddressee)
    INNER JOIN olap.customers ON public.orders.idcustomer = olap.customers.idcustomer)
    GROUP BY olap.time.idtime, olap.addressees.idaddressee, olap.customers.idcustomer, public.orders.price;
```

After running last set of queries I got error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "duplicate"
> LINE 1: duplicate key value violates unique constraint"

What can the problem be? Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably have the same combination of olap.time.idtime, olap.addressees.idaddressee, and olap.customers.idcustomer (which are going into the fields which comprise the primary key of olap.fact) matching to 2 or more records from public.orders.date which have different values for price.

Comment: Syntax error? That doesn't sound right.